# How to subset multiple rows from data.table fast on big data

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working with R-Studio and want to get multiple rows from a data.table.

Let's say I have a data.table with the following data:

```
Date                           Column 1
"01.02.2016 10:00:00  CEST"    10        
"01.02.2016 10:01:00  CEST"    12
"01.02.2016 10:02:00  CEST"    13
"01.02.2016 10:03:00  CEST"    11
"01.02.2016 10:04:00  CEST"    17
```

and I want to get the values from **"01.02.2016 10:00:30"** to **"01.02.2016 10:02:30"** like this:

```
    Date                       Column 1       
"01.02.2016 10:01:00  CEST"    12
"01.02.2016 10:02:00  CEST"    13
```

at the moment I achieve this by doing this:

```
x <- data.table[Date >= "01.02.2016 10:00:30  CEST" & Date <= "01.02.2016 10:02:30  CEST"]
```

But this is far too slow for me, because on a data.table with 600k rows it takes about 0.4 seconds.

Instead this is much much faster:

```
setkey(data.table, Date)
x <- prozessdaten.data.table[J(c("01.02.2016 10:01:00  CEST", "01.02.2016 10:02:00  CEST"))]
```

My Question is there a possibility to use the binary Search function J() with a specified time range and not exact values?

Comment: Your first step should be to parse the datetimes as POSIXct. I don't believe your code works / does what you think it does.

Comment: HI, I tested it and for me it works with characters. But I could as well parse them, but that doens't solve my problem :)

Comment: It only happens to be correct in this example. But check what `"01.02.2016 10:00:30" < "21.02.2015 10:02:30"` returns, for example

Comment: Oh...You got me! I made a huge mistake! Sry @Roland! Thanks for pointing out my mistake! Will edit the question with POSIXct objects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

data.table [v1.9.7+](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation#install-datatable-development-version) has implemented [non-equi joins](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features) and added a new function `inrange` which uses this new feature and can achieve what you want

```
## Loading data
library(data.table) #v 1.9.7+
DT <- data.table(date = c('01.02.2016 10:00:00','01.02.2016 10:01:00',
                          '01.02.2016 10:02:00','01.02.2016 10:03:00',
                          '01.02.2016 10:04:00'),
                 column1 = c(10, 12, 13, 11, 17))

## Converting to POSIXct class
DT[, date := as.POSIXct(date, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")]

## Validating that forder/bmerge kicks in 
options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)
DT[date %inrange% as.POSIXct(c("2016-02-01 10:00:30", "2016-02-01 10:02:30"))]
# forderv(query) took ... 0 secs
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs <~~~~~~~~ (Thanks to @Arun for fixing the bug)
# Generating final logical vector ... done in 0 secs
#                   date column1
# 1: 2016-02-01 10:01:00      12
# 2: 2016-02-01 10:02:00      13
```

---

Though, you should be aware that since data.table 1.9.4 [secondary keys](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-1) were implemented, meaning that for some variations of vector scans, after the first run a key is being added and from now on, even operations such as `==` and `%in%` are using `bmerge`. This doesn't seem to work on `POSIXct` class but you can observe this behavior on you numeric column `column1`

```
## Running for first time
options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)
DT[column1 == 10]
# Creating new index 'column1'
# forder took 0 sec <~~~ forder kicks in, hence first time is a bit slow
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
#                   date column1
# 1: 2016-02-01 10:00:00      10

## Running for second time and on
DT[column1 == 10]
# Using existing index 'column1'
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs <~~ bmerge kicks in from now on
#                   date column1
# 1: 2016-02-01 10:00:00      10
```

As Mentioned by @Jan, this is planned to be implemented for non-equi joins too [starting from v2.0.0](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1068)

---

**Edit (26/8/2016):**

As noted by @Arun, although `inrange` is using a binary join, it needs to sort the whole vector first in order to check whether *each* value in x is in between *any* of the intervals provided in lower, upper. 
In your case it is a little of an overhead because you are only comparing against two values, hence the recently rewritten in C `between` function will suit you better

```
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(x = sample(5e8))

system.time(res1 <- DT[x > 1e3L & x < 1e5L])
#  user  system elapsed 
# 10.23    1.22   11.45 

system.time(res2 <- DT[x %inrange% c(1e3L, 1e5L)])
# forderv(query) took ... 29.09 secs
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
# Generating final logical vector ... done in 0.43 secs
#  user  system elapsed 
# 29.28    0.70   30.06 

system.time(res3 <- DT[x %between% c(1e3L, 1e5L)])
# user  system elapsed 
# 2.01    2.60    0.84
```

So as you can see, although `bmerge` is almost instant, the sorting takes a lot of time. While `between` is the fastest because it doesn't need to convert `x` to a logical vector twice. Heck, `between` is so fast that `elapsed` is somehow smaller that `user` + `system`

Though, if your data is already sorted, then `inrange` catches up pretty well

```
setorder(DT, x)
system.time(res1 <- DT[x > 1e3L & x < 1e5L])
#  user  system elapsed 
# 10.41    1.02   11.45 

system.time(res2 <- DT[x %inrange% c(1e3L, 1e5L)])
# forderv(query) took ... 2.17 secs
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
# Generating final logical vector ... done in 0.44 secs
#  user  system elapsed 
# 2.47    0.71    3.20 

system.time(res3 <- DT[x %between% c(1e3L, 1e5L)])
#  user  system elapsed 
# 2.30    2.62    0.88
```

Comment: auto index for more operations is scheduled for 2.0.0 at the moment - [data.table#1068](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1068)

Comment: @Arun [fixed the bug](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1819) so now You can see `bmerge` kicking in- updated the post. You'll need the newest version on Gh

Comment: Note that if you've only one range, `between()` will be faster (especially now that it has been implemented in C and parallelised). `inrange` is much useful when dealing with subsetting more than 1 range. I'll optimise it further when used from within `DT[]`, soon (to use existing indices)..

Comment: @Arun `between` was my first thought, but after checking it, I saw that it is only doing a vector scan, or am I wrong?Also, would it be faster than Ops `Date >= & Date <=` attempt?

Comment: `inrange()` needs to compute the order vector.. which if you're just doing once isn't advantageous.. but we could reuse existing secondary index when used within `DT[]`. Also, now that I think of it, I can optimise `inrange()` like `between()` when there's only one range and parallelise. Then it'll be faster than `between()` due to binary search. `>= & <=` does vector scan *and* constructs two logical vectors... not the most efficient.

Comment: @Arun, ok, I'll run some benchmarks later to day when find some time. I'm wondering if it make sense to do this on `POSIXct` class or convert it to numeric? I'm not sure how `bmerge` handles `POSIXct` class internally

Comment: David, nice! Thanks. I'll try to figure out a way to reuse index so that the 2.17s is taken care of if an index already exists. Still for 1 intervals (on unsorted data), between might be slightly faster..